# SQL order of operations

Tags: sql, join, optimization, where-clause, sql-execution-plan

If I run the following SQL query

```
SELECT * 
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B
ON A.foo=B.foo
WHERE A.date = "Yesterday"
```

Does the `WHERE` statement get evaluated before or after the `JOIN`?

If after, what would be a better way to write this statement so that returns only rows in `A` from `"Yesterday"` are joined to `B`?

Comment: `what would be a better way to write this statement so that only rows in A from "Yesterday" are joined to B.` (late answer) -> `INNER JOIN`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It depends on the database.

On SQL Server, run: `SET SHOWPLAN_ALL ON` then run the query, you will get an idea of what happens when it runs.

Answer (score 8):

Your idea of "evaluation" is not correct as SQL is a declarative language.

BTW you can see the query execution plan. In MySQL prefix your query with keyword `describe` to see the execution plan.

Answer (score 6):

Semantically: After the JOIN.  But in this case, there is no difference in timing, because it's on the LEFT side of the JOIN.

As you already have it, "only rows in A from "Yesterday" are joined to B".

The optimizer is free to reorganize its order of operations depending on the equivalences in the relational algebra.

This returns only A.date="Yesterday" and joins B where it can find a match on foo:

```
SELECT * FROM A
LEFT JOIN B
    ON A.foo=B.foo
WHERE A.date="Yesterday"
```

This returns all A regardless of any criteria and joins B where A.date="Yesterday" AND it finds a match on foo:

```
SELECT * FROM A
LEFT JOIN B
    ON A.foo=B.foo
    AND A.date="Yesterday"
```

Comment: Just to understand, are you saying that putting the criteria in the WHERE clause is better from a performance perspective than putting it inside the JOIN clause?

Comment: It makes no difference to performance on an INNER JOIN and that is why the optimizer has more options to move things around on INNER JOINs.  On an OUTER JOIN (LEFT or RIGHT), it affects the semantics of the declaration, so performance is not usually the issue.

Answer (score 3):

The order of operations to satisfy a query is determined why the whim of the particular database's query optimizer. A query optimizer tries to product a good "query plan" (set of operations) based on what it can glean from the query and whatever statistics it has on hand about the database (which could include the cardinality of tables and certain distributions of data).

In your case, the answer may depend on whether you have a secondary index on A.date

Query optimization a fairly rich topic. The documentation for whatever database you're using will have a lot more to say about it.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on indexes and statistics.

You should show the execution path of the query to determine where (if any) optimizations should be applied.

Answer (score 1):

in SQL Server:

As a general rule of thumb, JOIN clauses are evaluated before WHERE clauses.

In case of complex joins that need filters in the join part, I write them along with my join

```
SELECT *
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B
    ON A.Foo1 = B.Foo1
    And A.Date = 'Yesterday'
OUTER JOIN C
    ON B.Foo2 = C.Foo2
JOIN D
    ON B.Foo3 = D.Foo3
```

Comment: This does not have the same meaning when you use it inside the LEFT JOIN.  In the LEFT JOIN, when the criteria aren't satisfied, the LEFT rows are still returned, and any columns from the RIGHT are NULL.

Comment: I stand corrected on the example provided.  I was trying to make the point of putting the where part of a clause along with the appropriate join.  I have corrected the statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * FROM A WHERE Date = 'Yesterday') A
LEFT JOIN B 
    ON A.Foo1 = B.Foo1 
OUTER JOIN C 
    ON B.Foo2 = C.Foo2 
JOIN D 
    ON B.Foo3 = D.Foo3
```